# How to rotate a specific object in openGL?

Tags: opengl-es, rotation, graphics

I have some objects on the screen and would like to rotate only one of them. I tried using the glRotatef(...) function but turns out glRotatef(...) rotates all my objects (rotates the camera, maybe?).
How can I rotate only one?

I use openGL ES 1.1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need the rotation to be in effect only when the geometry you're interested in is being drawn.

```
... draw stuff ...
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
... draw rotated stuff ...
glPopMatrix();
... draw more stuff ...
```

Answer (score 4):

[Tutorial #4 from NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rotation/14001/) shows how to do that precisely.

Also, you might want to take a look at this:

[OpenGL Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918/opengl-rotation)

Comment: This is highly highly outdated now. Opengl has become lower level and much harder to use. Nowadays people directly write code that runs on the GPU.

Comment: @BrianYeh Well, it is a 10 year old question & answer, after all. All posts on Stackoverflow will suffer from aging so it is important that people keep asking questions and new blood like you help come up with relevant answers.

Comment: just amending the question for future lurkers who happen upon your answer so they know it's outdated. Totally understood that it's 10 years old.