# Rotate Objects OpenGL GLFW

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have some 3D objects. But I want to rotate only some of them with rotation effect. I need to rotate the objects, not the camera. How can I do it using GLFW? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 3):

First, the rotation in OpenGL works the same way if you use GLFW or not.
If you use OpenGL without shaders (fixed pipeline), for rotate only the object A in your scene you should:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();             // save the current GL_MODELVIEW matrix 
glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);  // rotate your object
drawObjectAHere();          // draw object A
glPopMatrix();              // restore the GL_MODELVIEW matrix
```

More information here:
[How to rotate a specific object in openGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515059/how-to-rotate-a-specific-object-in-opengl)

If you use shaders, you should create the rotation matrix yourself, and send it to your vertex shader.
This library can be useful for create your rotation matrix : http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html
And I hope, this tutorial will be useful too, to understand how use this matrix in your shaders, to rotate your object : http://www.geeks3d.com/20111115/how-to-compute-the-position-in-a-vertex-shader-glsl-opengl-part-3/

Comment: If the object has been drawn, how to move it and rotate it around base axis (X, Y, or Z)?

Comment: You cannot move or rotate your object after draw it. You should first setup the matrix and then draw it. For move and rotate an object, you can combinate glRotatef(angle,0.0,1.0,0.0); follow by glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0); Here the object will rotate, then translate. So the object rotate on itself at the coordinate 0.0,0.0,-5.0.